# How can I use a @types which is a Module from a TypeScript file which is not a Module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

### The background:

I am converting a large ~3,000 inline `<script>` from a web-page into a TypeScript file (`PageScripts.ts`) which will then be used by the page as `<script src="PageScripts.js" defer></script>`.

The script uses SortableJS which has [a `@types` package available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sortablejs). The `*.d.ts` files are available on GitHub here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/sortablejs

### The original script:

Here's the portion of the original JavaScript from the HTML page that's causing problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var sortableOptions = {
        dataIdAttr: 'my-id',
        onEnd: function( ev ) {

            // do stuff
        }
    };

} );

</script>
```

I added the @types by running `npm install --save @types/sortablejs`.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
  {
        "compileOnSave": true,
        "compilerOptions": {
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "strict": true,
            "noEmitOnError": true,
            "removeComments": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "target": "es5" /* es5 for IE11 support. */,
            "typeRoots": [
                "node_modules/@types",
                "JSFiles/System.Web.dll/Types"
            ],
            "lib": [
                "es5",
                "dom",
                "dom.iterable",
                "es2015.core",
                "es2015.collection",
                "es2015.symbol",
                "es2015.iterable",
                "es2015.promise"
            ]
        },
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
```

### The TypeScript:

I converted the above script fragment to this TypeScript in `PageScripts.ts`:

```
import Sortable = require("sortablejs");

// ...

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var sortableOptions = {
        dataIdAttr: 'my-id',
        onEnd: function( ev: Sortable.SortableEvent ) {

            // do stuff
        }
    };

} );
```

This compiles without any errors, however because the TypeScript file has a single `import` statement it causes TypeScript to compile the file to its own JavaScript module, which means it cannot be used directly by web-pages because TypeScript adds this to the start of the output `PageScripts.js` file:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

...which causes a browser script error because `exports` is not defined.

So I changed it to use the `/// <reference types=/>` instead:

```
/// <reference types="sortablejs" />

// ...

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var sortableOptions = {
        dataIdAttr: 'my-id',
        onEnd: function( ev: Sortable.SortableEvent ) {        <--- "Cannot find namespace 'Sortable'."

            // do stuff
        }
    };

} );
```

But now `PageScripts.ts` won't compile because `tsc` complains that it "Cannot find namespace 'Sortable'."

The IDE code-fixes menu says the fix is to add an `import Sortable = require("sortablejs")` line - but that means my `PageScripts.js` file is a module again, argh!

I also cannot set `module: 'none'` in my `tsconfig.json` because I have other TypeScript files in my project which *are* modules and I don't want to affect them by changing global settings. Is there a per-file module setting or anything?

### The question:

So - how can I use the types from `@types/sortablejs` without causing my `PageScripts.js` file to become a module?

Comment: Have you tried adding another tsconfig file with appropriate settings?

Comment: @AlekseyL. How would another tsconfig file help? And what "appropriate settings" are you referring to? I'm using TypeScript to compile and generate global scripts for use in web-browsers going back to IE11 so I simply cannot use modules at all.

Comment: _I also cannot set module: 'none' in my tsconfig.json_ that's what you said

Comment: @AlekseyL. Setting `module: "none"` breaks other files in my project for unrelated reasons.

Comment: That's why you need separate config for this specific file

Comment: @Dai did you find a solution? I've hit the exact same problem with Sortable

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `sortablejs` d.ts files into `includes` array in `tsconfig.json` file, it will make this lib available globally.